# Logged in user home page error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I added a `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` to my PagesController to override the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in my ApplicationController for  un-signed in users to access site. Now when a signed in user clicks on the home button they are being sent to the un-signed in users home page

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.plan.name == "mentor"
      mentor_root_path
    elsif current_user.plan.name == "mentee"
      mentee_root_path
    end
  end
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

class PagesController < ApplicationController

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def home
    @mentor_plan = Plan.find(1)
    @mentee_plan = Plan.find(2)
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Comment: And what's the problem? That's expected right? You can check for current_user in the home method and redirect to another page.

Comment: @bo-oz...I've been working with someone on this issue and it doesn't seem to be the `before_action` that's causing the problem. My `plan.html.erb' files aren't being accessed in the layout file. Thanks